# Is the moment of zero velocity identical for objects of differing mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, velocity

Assume we have two perfect spheres of identical size but different mass (e.g., one made of steel and one made of enamel) and an environment where the only forces in play are gravity and velocity (i.e., no friction, wind resistance, temperature, etc.).

If our two spheres are launched straight up with identical force, each will be at zero velocity for a small amount of time.

Questions:

1. Are the periods of zero velocity the same or are they different?
2. If they are different because of their differing mass, is there a
   lay-friendly explanation for why the mass results in differing
   periods of zero velocity?
3. Stepping away from the hypothetical environment, do things like friction matter?

Answer (score 1):

Since gravity is constantly acting on both spheres once released, both objects have constant downward directed acceleration and, thus, have zero velocity only for infinitesimal time.

That is to say, the velocity of both objects is not constant at any time between their release and their impact with the ground.

Assuming the objects have different upward speeds when released, the *instant* in time when each has zero velocity not be the same, i.e., they will reach zero velocity at different times.

Adding friction will alter the problem but not change the fact that both will have zero velocity for infinitesimal time.

Comment: I think I worded my question badly. I'm asking about the -duration- of zero velocity for each sphere, rather than how long it takes to reach zero velocity.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @DWRoelands, no worries.  The duration is infinitesimal which is to say that, during the trip up and down,  sphere 1 and sphere 2 have zero velocity at time value $t_1$ and $t_2$ respectively and non-zero velocity at all other time values.

Comment: I understand that the duration of zero velocity is infinitesimally small;  is it the same for both spheres?

Comment: @DWRoelands, I'm afraid I don't completely understand what you're asking.  For either sphere, the acceleration is $-g$.  Thus, if $t_0$ is the time value when the velocity is zero, $v(t_0) = 0$, then it is the case, that $$v(t_0 \pm dt) = \mp\; g\,dt$$  So, under the assumption that the acceleration of each sphere is the constant $-g$, the equation above holds for either sphere.

Comment: Let me try rephrasing my question.  One of our hypothetical spheres is launched upward and reaches zero velocity at time value t1.  The sphere then begins falling at time value t2.  What I am asking is: is the difference between t1 and t2 the same for both spheres?

Comment: @DWRoelands, in an earlier comment, you wrote:  *"I understand that the duration of zero velocity is infinitesimally small"*.  But, it that were true, you would not then ask *"is the difference between t1 and t2 the same for both spheres?"*.  There is no finite difference between t1 and t2.  That is to say, the difference is not zero while being immeasurably small.